# xcode SASlideMenu not working in latest iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, saslidemenu

I am working on an existing project which is using SASlideMenu. It's working fine in most of the devices but it's not showing anything in the latest iOS 10 devices.  What can I do in order to fix this? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your table for the menu. Seems like something problem with the table. may be some problem with the cells